# Patterns for testing the step catalog in Python Behave

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

At my company our Behave step catalog is growing quite rapidly. It's becoming more and more clear that we need tests for the actual steps. E.g. that a certain given step set up data as it is expected to do.

For a BDD framework like Behave it would be nice if the actual framework guided you (or atleast supported you) into writing step implementations in a BDD fashion :-) I can't find anything like that however.

Anyone out there with a nice pattern for testing the actual steps?

Comment: So you want to write tests... for your tests? Oh my god. May I inquire how big the software that you are testing? Just want to know at which point the project reaches "tests all the way down" stage.

Comment: Sounds like you should have a code review for the existing step implementations, and guidelines for how step implementations should be written or what should be tested. As for the framework guiding you? There's plenty of documentation on *how* to use behave--don't forget that it's merely a tool, and it's up to you how *you* use it. As for design patterns for automated testing: check some out [here](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-in-automation-testing).

Comment: I can understand that it sounds overkill :-). The reason is that one component defines steps and many others defines features. We want to make sure a release of the first component doesn't cause problems in the others. We have code reviews but are looking for test coverage also.